# Overlaying DIVs has made button un-clickable, despite being on top

Tags: html, css

I have a button that is sitting ontop of both a full screen video and an opaque overlay.

```
<section id="contact" class="threemonth-section">
    <div class="container">
    <video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" muted="true" loop="loop" volume="0" > 
    <source src="video2.webm" type="video/webm"> 
    <source src="video2.m4v" type="video/mp4"> Video not supported 
    </video>

    <div id="overlay2"></div>

    <div id="welcomingText">


                    <h2 class="welcoming">Welcome</h2>
                    <h3 class="to">to</h3>
                    <h1 class="mySite">my site</h1>


            </div>
           <button type="button" class="button"></button>  


 </div>




</section>
```

and here is the CSS for each part of this.

```
.threemonth-section {
height: 105%;
width: 100%;
position:relative;
display:table;
padding-top: 200px;
z-index:-5;
text-align: center;
background: url(../img/3monthNew.png) no-repeat center center scroll;

background-size:cover;
}

#video_background { position: absolute; z-index:-4; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; width: auto; height: 105%;  overflow: hidden; }

#overlay2{
background-color:#000;

height:100%;
width:100%;
opacity:0.5;

z-index:-2;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px; right: 0px; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; width: auto; height: auto;  overflow: hidden; 

}

#welcomingText{

margin-top:50px;
height:100%;
width:100%;
z-index:200;
color:#fff;

padding-top:15%;
z-index:-1;
margin-bottom:auto;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px; right: 0px; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; width: auto; height: auto;  overflow: hidden; 

}

.button{



background: transparent url('button.png') no-repeat top;   
height: 50px;
width:50px;
background-size:100%;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;

background-repeat:no-repeat;


margin-left: 267px;


}
```

I can't figure out why my button is un-clickable. I know its got no actions but It's being overlayed by something but I can't figure out why. Both positioning in my HTML and the z-index lead me to believe it should be on top?

It's probably pretty obvious but I've been staring at this for hours. Any ideas?

Comment: Use 'inspect element' in developer tools in your browser to find out what, if anything, is overlaying the button.

Comment: working here...: http://jsfiddle.net/oxhy0pz5/

Comment: @sh-ado-w yeah, I'm starting to think it's something either to do with the video or me interfering with bootstrap somewhere. Would it be worth me uploading my actual code to my server and posting it here to better show the issue do you reckon?

Comment: you can try it but better in new question so more people notice it :)